# show images associated with particular user in meteorjs

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and am making an app where users can upload the images.That images are can be viewed by everyone.
but, I am facing problem to show the pictures uploaded by particular user.

for eg: when I click on user profile it should display all the images uploaded by that user.

please help to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show: (a) the schema for your images collection especially how it relates to users and (b) the blaze template and helper code for your user profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define a helper, something like this:

```
Template.imagesList.helpers({
    images: function () {
        return Images.find({_id: this._id}});
    }
});
```